# How to update the HighCharts title using drill-up when there are multiple charts on same page?

Tags: highcharts

I have built a set of tabs that each contain similar Highcharts charts, but with different data. I have all of the charts functioning properly with one exception...

How it should work is each chart has drill down information and when you drill down from the main chart the chart title changes to that of the drill down title. Then when you drill up it should return to the chart name.

However, what is happening is after the drill up in any chart, the names are changing to the name of the last chart in the last tab (there are five charts all together), rather than to their respective chart titles. I know there is a problem with a global variable here, but am not sure how to localize it for each chart. Here is sample code from the first chart, followed by that which I used in the second chart. I have omitted all but the relevant code to save space.

Each chart has the same code except that I've changed the chart name for each. Which works for localizing all the code except for this particular problem. Any ideas out there?

First chart

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
    drillUpText: "< < Regresar"
    }
    });

    var title = 'IDD-Mex Indice';
    chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
    type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: '#f3f7fa',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        chart.setTitle({ text: e.point.name });
      },
      drillup: function(e) {
        chart.setTitle({ text: title });
      }
      }
     },

  title: {
    text: title
   },


    //Second chart

    Highcharts.setOptions({
   lang: {
    drillUpText: "< < Regresar"
    }
    });


    var title = 'Dimensión 1: Índice de los Ciudadanos';
    chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container-2', {
    chart: {
    type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: '#f3f7fa',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(f) {
        chart2.setTitle({ text: f.point.name });
      },
      drillup: function(f) {
        chart2.setTitle({ text: title });
      }
    }
    },

    title: {
    text: title
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems everything works fine with `drilldown` and multiple charts on the same page. You should put all the titles in one array or name them differently. Having variables with the same name `title` initialized in a couple of places on the same scope is a bad idea. Check the demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
var titles = [
 'IDD-Mex Indice',
  'Dimensión 1: Índice de los Ciudadanos'
];

Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#f3f7fa',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        this.setTitle({
          text: e.point.name
        });
      },
      drillup: function(e) {
        this.setTitle({
          text: titles[0]
        });
      }
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: titles[0]
  },
  series: [{
   data: [{
     y: 1,
      name: 'test1',
      drilldown: '1'
    }, 2, 1]
  }],
  drilldown: {
   series: [{
     id: '1',
     data: [3, 4, 5]
    }]
  }
})

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#f3f7fa',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(f) {
        this.setTitle({
          text: f.point.name
        });
      },
      drillup: function(f) {
        this.setTitle({
          text: titles[1]
        });
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: titles[1]
  },
  series: [{
   data: [{
     y: 2,
      name: 'test2',
      drilldown: '2'
    }, 1, 3]
  }],
  drilldown: {
   series: [{
     id: '2',
     data: [5, 5, 5]
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zn4503eu/